# SSRS - Repeat first row in Details group when second row overflows to second page

Tags: reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working in SSRS 2008R2. I have a query that will return several pairs of text fields, essentially like this:

```
SELECT TopTextField, BottomTextField
FROM myTable
WHERE someValue = paramValue
```

I have a table that simply uses the details Group to display these one over the other, like this:
[image]

Here is my problem: often times the BottomTextField value can be very large, and will spill over onto another page. When this happens, I would like the TopTextField row to appear above BottomTextField on the concurrent pages as well. I cannot put it in the header since it is a derived field from the query and since there are multiple value pairs it will be different on different pages. I have tried setting the Static object for the row to repeat on each page in Advanced Mode, but that did not work. At this point I'm not even sure what I'm trying to do can be done with the tool. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this? Thank you.

(Side note: please don't "mark as duplicate" unless the other question solves this... I've found a lot of questions that are reasonably similar to this, but they have all been trying to accomplish different things and did not solve the problem. Thanks)

Comment: I don't think this is possible...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to repeat the details parent group Set it up as the above image.

[image]